# Finding the height wherein the given are only 2 angles of depression .

Tags: trigonometry

Can someone please help me with this problem? I really can't get it right.

*

> **From the top of the tower, the angle of depression of the base of the flagpole is 51 degrees, while from 2 floors below, the angle of
>   depression of the base of the flagpole is 47 degrees. If each floor is
>   12 m high, what is the height of the tower?**

*
 Please. I really need help.

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram? There's an ASA triangle to solve.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out, draw a diagram.

Let the height of the second observation point (above the ground) be h m.

Then, that of the first observation point is h + 2*12 m.

Assume that the flagpole is x m away from the tower.

You now have two right angled triangles with sufficient data to let you setup 2 equations to eliminate x and get h.

Don't forget the required height is h + 2*12 m.